# Getting error of "Provided owner is not allowed"

Tags: web3.js, error

I have to send multiple transactions simultaneously so, if there is no token account in the sender or receiver wallet then it first creates the token account and then signs other single transaction one after the other.
I am getting the error on the second transaction after creating the token account simultaneously when there is no token account in the sender wallet but it is working fine  when there is no token account in the receiver wallet

```
const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  data.sender,
  mint1,
  data.sender,
  signTransaction
  true
)

const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  data.sender,
  mint2,
  address,
  signTransaction
  true
)

const transferTransaction = createTransferInstruction(
  fromTokenAccount.address,
  toTokenAccount.address,
  data.sender,
  amountInLamports,
  [],
  splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
)
finalTransaction.add(transferTransaction)
```

"getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount" is the custom method in which it executes the transaction of creating the token account first if there is no token account in sender or receiver wallet. So I am getting the error of "Provided owner not allowed" when executing "finalTransaction" if and only if there is no token account in sender wallet.
Here is the getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount method

```
async function getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection: Connection,
      payer: PublicKey,
      mint: PublicKey,
      owner: PublicKey,
      signTransaction:SignerWalletAdapterProps["signTransaction"],
      allowOwnerOffCurve = false,
      commitment?: Commitment,
      programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      associatedTokenProgramId = ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    ) {
      const associatedToken = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        mint,
        owner,
        allowOwnerOffCurve,
        programId,
        associatedTokenProgramId
      )
    
      let account
      try {
        account = await getAccountInfo(
          connection,
          associatedToken,
          commitment,
          programId
        )
      } catch (error: any) {
        if (
          error.message === "TokenAccountNotFoundError" ||
          error.message === "TokenInvalidAccountOwnerError"
        ) {
          try {
            transaction = new Transaction().add(
              createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
                payer,
                associatedToken,
                owner,
                mint,
                programId,
                associatedTokenProgramId
              )
            )
    
            const blockHash = await connection.getRecentBlockhash()
            transaction.feePayer = await payer
            transaction.recentBlockhash = await blockHash.blockhash
            const signed = await signTransaction(transaction)
    
            const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(
              signed.serialize()
            )
    
            await connection.confirmTransaction(signature)
          } catch (error: unknown) {}
    
          // Now this should always succeed
          account = await getAccountInfo(
            connection,
            associatedToken,
            commitment,
            programId
          )
        } else {
          throw error
        }
      }
    
      if (!account.mint.equals(mint.toBuffer()))
        throw Error("TokenInvalidMintError")
      if (!account.owner.equals(owner.toBuffer()))
        throw new Error("TokenInvalidOwnerError")
    
      return account
    }
```

Comment: How do you create the associated token account. Show us the code

Comment: I have added in the decription

Comment: @vicyyn Any clue about this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only transfer between accounts of the same mint, and here there are two mints specified, `mint1` and `mint2`. The first account is for `mint1`, and the second account is for `mint2` currently.

Can you try changing the second token account creation to:

```
const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  data.sender,
  mint1,
  address,
  signTransaction
  true
)
```